# UK visit visa refusal due to misunderstanding

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

UK visa (visit) application was rejected due to a mistake. Officials read the bank statement wrong. There is 300,000+ INR in the account in form of RD, which is normally shown in the statement as MOD balance on the top left. Officials just checked the closing balance of 132 INR (at the bottom right) and rejected the application.

1. Can I ask for an administrative review stating the error? If yes, how?
2. Is there any process or method of appeal against this gross error?
3. Does NRA mean I can't submit a new application for 28 days?
4. Which is better and faster, a new application or an appeal (if any)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What on earth is RD and MOD? Did you expect the ECO to know what those acronyms mean?

Comment: I am sure they did not 'just check the closing balance' because they always want to see a _pattern of transactions_ that is consistent with the rest of your application.

Comment: NRA means ‘no right of appeal’. There is no legal right to an administrative review or appeal for Standard Visit Visas https://www.gov.uk/ask-for-a-visa-administrative-review. A new application is the only realistic option, making sure to explain how to read the financial statements provided if they are not clear/ in a standard/typical format (personally, I’d pay attention to the closing balance figure as well when assessing your overall circumstances; I assume ECOs in your location are familiar with typical documents).

Comment: If you have 300000 INR and plan to spend 280000 INR for your trip, while showing no evidence of income, even if the ECO had taking into account the MOD balance, they probably would have rejected the application as well. At the very least, you would need to show the statement for the other account (so they see the pattern of deposits), and some justification of your income...

Comment: For other readers, MOD = multiple option deposit, which is called a [sweep account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_account) elsewhere. RD = [Recurring Deposit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurring_deposit), a term deposit or CD that lets you pay in over time.

Comment: `Is there any process or method of appeal against this gross error?` I don't see a gross error. I see a poorly prepared application on your part.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the issues around money which @Traveller has covered in comments, the letter mentioned that you have not documented the circumstances and whereabouts of all immediate family members.

It also mentions that you have never been out of India before.

You will have to address both issues in any new application. Don't just focus on the money.

Comment: Thnk u every1 for ur inputs. Much Appreciated.

Comment: Plz guide if dere is online resource avbl to help validate fresh applications correctness. Cant afford to take that risk now

Comment: I do not know of any online resource. You should consider getting a lawyer to help you. Here is a site which lists lawyers with relevant experience http://www.ilpa.org.uk/ but they will be quite expensive.